# Changing the value of a non-struct with a pointer receiver

Tags: go

If I have a type which is not a struct how do I change its value with a pointer receiver?

For example, given the [following code](https://play.golang.org/p/HW53RD_h1V):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type MyInt int

func (i *MyInt) Change() {
    newValue := MyInt(32)
    i = &newValue
}

func main() {
    myInt := MyInt(64)
    fmt.Println(myInt)
    myInt.Change()
    fmt.Println(myInt)
}
```

It outputs:

```
64
64
```

Why does it not output the following:

```
64
32
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're changing the value of the **pointer** `i`, not the **value** at which the pointer is pointing.

You will see your expected output by using the [`*` operator](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators):

```
*i = newValue
```

https://play.golang.org/p/mKsKC0lsj9

Comment: I see. My confusion was caused by thinking `*i` was a way of **getting** the value at the address of `i`, and therefore not usable for setting values. Not sure why I thought that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

for your function define:

```
func (i *MyInt) Change() {
    newValue := MyInt(32)
    i = &newValue
}
```

when you call this function:

```
myInt := MyInt(64)
myInt.Change()
```

the value of `myInt` will pass to `i`, so after call `func (i *MyInt) Change()`, you only modify the `i`, not `myInt`.